# Django- url not displaying page despite changing

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

This is the index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1>list of  {{title}}</h1>
{% if questions %}
    <ul>
        {% for question in questions %}
        <li>
           <a href="/polls/{{question.id}}/details/"> {{question.title}}</a>

        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
        {% else %}
        <p>there is a no question available</p>
        {% endif %}


{% endblock %}
```

details.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<H2>Details Page</H2>
<h3>{{question.title}}</h3>
{% for choice in question.choices %}
<p>{{choice.text}}({{choice.votes}})</p>
{% empty %}
<p>There is no choice available for this Question</p>
{% endfor %}


<p>Poll is created by {{question.created_by.first_name}}</p>

{% endblock %}
```

This is base.html

```
{%load static%}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>WebPage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="(%static 'css/custom.css'%)">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to My Page</h1>
{%  block content %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

And poll.urls

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from poll.views import *
urlpatterns = [
    url('', index, name='polls_list'),
    url('<int:id>/details/', details, name='polls_details')
]
```

So this is what happens I have 3 questions that display on the index.html, on clicking any of them it changes to the proper url but does not open the requested page. How do I solve this. Do keep in mind that i just started django two days ago so pardon my naivety.Thanks

Comment: Tell me if you need some other file too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In urls.py you are using the `url()` function but `path` syntax. Change it to path:

```
path('', index, name='polls_list'),
path('<int:id>/details/', details, name='polls_details')
```

**Edit** If you're using pre-2.0, path syntax is not supported, so you need to use regexes:

```
url('^$', index, name='polls_list'),
url('^(?P<id>\d+)/details/$', details, name='polls_details')
```

Comment: I am using 1.11.13 django, path is not included. I think it's from 2.0.

Comment: Then you need to use the regex format, see my update.

Comment: Thanks it worked. what did you just do btw? Also the second line should have url instead of path

Comment: Thanks, edited. I don't understand your question though.

Comment: I meant what's a regex, just a minor explanation is sufficient.Thanks, I'd upvote but  my vote doesn't count

Comment: You can accept the answer, it's good to do that as an indication to future searchers that it solved the problem. Regex is short for regular expression, it's a way of defining search patterns in strings - in this case that a URL can match against.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please edit your url as per the code below. Django can handle the url creation.

```
<a href="{% url 'polls_details' question.id %}"> {{question.title}}</a>
```

Comment: NoReverseMatch at /polls/
Reverse for 'polls_details' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['polls/<int:id>/details/'] ............... tried your suggestion gives this error.

Comment: which django version you are using

Comment: 1.11.13 version. It's the latest one available for this python version

Comment: Now try this method, after @Daniel Roseman changes, You should not hard cord the url like that.